# Upload a PDF file from web Flutter to php server

Tags: flutter, dart

An Android application that works on the web. I need to upload a PDF file and use it on the web
Uploading a file from Android works correctly for you to the web, showing many errors
After trying a lot, this is the last code

```
Future<int> uploadFileWeb(String likePage,file,String filename,Map<String,String> data)async{

var request = http.MultipartRequest(
  'POST', _getUtl(likePage),
);
Map<String,String>headers= _getHeaders();
headers["Content-type"]="multipart/form-data";
request.headers.addAll(headers);
if(data.isNotEmpty){
  request.fields.addAll(data);
}

request.files.add(
  http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
      "file", file,
      contentType:MediaType('files', 'pdf')
  ),
);

var response = await request.send();
if(response.statusCode==200){
  await response.stream.bytesToString().then((value) {
    print(value);
    var jsonResponse = json.decode(value);
    fromJson(jsonResponse['result']);
  });
  return 1;
}else{
  return 0;
}
}
```

php code

```
    public function uploadFile()
{
    $NAMFPOST = "file";

    $uploadDir = 'files/'; // مجلد حفظ الملفات

    $ddd = $_FILES[$NAMFPOST]["name"];

    $FILE_PATH = $_FILES[$NAMFPOST]["tmp_name"];  // Full path to your local file
    $uploadedFile = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($FILE_PATH, $uploadedFile)) {
        return 'File uploaded successfully! ' . $ddd;
    } else {
        return 'Error uploading file!';
    }
}
```

error in php

Undefined array key "file"
and
Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
...............................

error flutter

```
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 297:3  throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/convert_patch.dart 38:5          _parseJson
dart-sdk/lib/convert/json.dart 610:36                                        convert
dart-sdk/lib/convert/json.dart 216:41                                        decode
packages/yourdoctor/serves/getDataApi.dart 113:33                            <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                         runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 162:18                                   handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 838:44                                   handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 867:13                                   _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 634:7                                    [_complete]
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1094:13                                       <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1582:9                                          runGuarded
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_impl.dart 392:7                                    sendDone
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_impl.dart 402:7                                    [_sendDone]
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_impl.dart 291:7                                    [_close]
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_transformers.dart 87:11                            [_close]
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_transformers.dart 21:5                             close
dart-sdk/lib/convert/string_conversion.dart 241:5                            close
dart-sdk/lib/convert/string_conversion.dart 295:7                            close
dart-sdk/lib/convert/chunked_conversion.dart 78:5                            close
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_transformers.dart 132:7                            [_handleDone]
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1582:9                                          runGuarded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select file

```
startWebFilePicker() async {
html.FileUploadInputElement uploadInput = html.FileUploadInputElement();
uploadInput.multiple = true;
uploadInput.draggable = true;
uploadInput.click();

uploadInput.onChange.listen((event) {
  final files = uploadInput.files;
  final fileF = files![0];
  
  reader.onLoadEnd.listen((event) {
    fileWeb =
        const Base64Decoder().convert(reader.result.toString().split(",").last);
    file = fileWeb;
    callback();
  });
  reader.readAsDataUrl(fileF);
 });
}
```

and  upload

```
request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', file.file!,
    contentType: MediaType('application', 'json'), filename: file.nameFile));
var response = await request.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Undefined array key "file" in PHP.** The PHP script tries to access $_FILES['file'], however it appears you're using a different key ($NAMFPOST = "file";). You should utilize $NAMFPOST rather than hardcoding 'file' into the $_FILES array. Update your PHP script accordingly.
here some example :

```
$ddd = $_FILES[$NAMFPOST]["name"];
$FILE_PATH = $_FILES[$NAMFPOST]["tmp_name"];  // Full path to your local file
$uploadedFile = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES[$NAMFPOST]['name']);
```

Comment: `however it appears you're using a different key` But it is the same key. There should be no difference between `$_FILES['file']` and `$_FILES[$NAMFPOST]` since `$NAMFPOST='file'`;

Comment: Same key.. The error is that the $_FILES function is empty.. Confirm from
var_dump($_FILES)